# Substitute Schrödinger Equation by complex analysis, was the substitution correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

Known that

$$
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}=\frac{i\hbar }{2m}\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V\Psi
\tag 1
$$

By taking the complex conjugate of the equation, obtain

$$
\frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial t}=-\frac{i\hbar }{2m}\frac{\partial^2\Psi^*}{\partial x^2}+\frac{i}{\hbar}V\Psi^*
\tag 2
$$

where the derivative of the complex conjugate equal to complex conjugate of the derivative.

However, if we substitute $\Psi$ by $\Psi^*$ directly, we obtain
$$
 \frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial t}=\frac{i\hbar }{2m}\frac{\partial^2\Psi^*}{\partial x^2}+\frac{i}{\hbar}V\Psi^*
\tag 3
$$

Thus if we compare the last two equation, then we obtain the following function that 
$$
\partial_x^2\Psi=0
\tag 4
$$
and
$$
\partial_t\Psi^*=\frac{i}{\hbar} V\Psi^*.
\tag 5
$$

My question was that:

1. Was equation 3 correct? I think it does because if the function was continuous differentialble in $C$, then by complex analysis we could rewrite the function as $\Psi(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.
2. What happened in equation 4 and equation 5?  was they correct? especially, why $\partial_x^2\Psi=0$ the particle was not accelerate?

(This was not a homework question, because usually people only consider eq. 2 which was in the textbook.)

Comment: I recommend that you edit your post to reword all the 'is my equation correct?' stuff for the reason that 'check my work' questions are considered off-topic and are generally down-voted and closed.

Comment: i do not understand what you are doing. if you just replace psi by psi* then the sign of the last term in eq. 3 is incorrect. but in any case it is not because psi satisfies an equation that psi* satisfies the same equation.

Comment: I wasn’t sure either (that’s why I was asking the question ), $\Psi^*$ was the complex conjugate of the equation. In eq3 i simply replaced $\psi$ by $pis^*$ which could be done through complex analysis if assume equation was continuous and différentiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that some function $\Psi$ satisfies a differential equation does not imply that $\Psi^*$ satisfies the equation too, so everything after equation 2 is nonsensical.

It is, of course, *possible* that $\Psi^*$ also satisfies the differential equation, but that would be a special case.  I'm not sure why you would think otherwise.  For example, the equation
$$y' + iy = 0$$
is solved by functions of the form $Ce^{-ix}$ but not by their complex conjugates.

Lastly, acceleration is not a particularly meaningful concept in quantum mechanics.  Position is generally not a well-defined property of a state, much less the *derivatives* of position with respect to time.

Comment: In a strange way I thought the same. However, I couldn't give me a proper proof.  Because the complex conjugate of derivative=derivative of complex conjugate.(I have checked that in Mathstachexchange.) Thus $(\partial_t \Psi(x,t))^*=\partial_t (\Psi(x,t))^*$. If you couldn't accept that just yet, including me, then a usual trick was that $\Psi(x,t)$ could always be written as the combination of its real and imaginary part. i.e. $\Psi(t)=f(x,t)+ig(x,t)$ where $f,g,$ were real functions. Thus you could put it back into the equation

Comment: , even If $V$ dependent of $x,t$ it still worked. (If you couldn't write it analytically, you cold write it numerically, both worked,)

Comment: Your case was exactly what I said and even better, we have analytic solution to $f,g$ by using Euler identity, and if you check it's the same.

Comment: @JC I'm perfectly aware that the derivative of the conjugate is equal to the conjugate of the derivative, but that doesn't mean that the conjugate satisfies the same differential equation.  $e^{-ix}$ satisfies the equation I wrote, but if you try to plug in $e^{+ix}$ then it *doesn't work*.